# How to save cucumber reports in a path which contains spaces?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, yaml, watir

We have a bulk automation suite with multiple tags that will be executed on daily basis using cucumber.

We want the cucumber HTML reports to be automatically stored into our network shared results folder. The issue here is , we are able to save the report in the path if the folder names in the path doesn't have space in it. But in the path we need, we have folders with space in the folder name. Please find the below examples.

The below example is the profile we are using in cucumber.yml which doesnt work because there is a space in the folder name "sub folder"

```
check_report: --format pretty --format html --out=//networkPathParent/child_folder/sub folder/features_report.html
```

But  if we are trying to save the report in the path where the folder name is not having space then it works. The below example works.

```
check_report: --format pretty --format html --out=//networkPathParent/child_folder/subfolder/features_report.html
```

Can some one help us getting the cucumber html to be stored in the network path even though the path has folders with space in the name ? We tried with multiple escape sequence characters but no success.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried just wrapping that parameter in quotes?  `... "--out=//networkPathParent/child_folder/sub folder/features_report.html"` ??   btw  I've seen so many things get broken by this (just basic copy or move commands for example) that to avoid the hassle of having to use quotes or wildcards, I always recommend that you NEVER put spaces in the names of subdirectories.   it's like technical micro-debt when you do that.

Comment: parameter in quotes doesn't work. I tried with ruby file move  and it worked.

Comment: bah  just noticed I had first quote in wrong place in my comment above..  should have been
`--out="//networkPathParent/child_folder/sub folder/features_report.html"`

Comment: Even i haven't noticed the wrong location of the quotes you placed . But still I tried having the whole path alone in quotes and it still doesn't work and throws error stating the parth doesn't exist .

Comment: Don't know what else to suggest then..  frankly having spaces in sub-directory names is never a good idea and always causes pain in one way or another.. especially with scripting and command line operations.   If you don't get a response here, perhaps try with the Cucumber google group, that's a primary support venue for Cucumber